# Constructor with Resources.Load?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class AssetList{
     private GameObject bullet;
     public GameObject Bullet{
         get{ return bullet; }
         set{ bullet = value; } 
     }

     public AssetList(){
        bullet = Resources.Load ("Prefabs/bullet_1") as GameObject; 
     }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Load is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead.

Obviously the Load() won't work because Unity has build it to only work for Start() and Awake().

What can I do to make my constructor work? Is there an alternative to assign and load a prefab for the variable bullet?

Comment: There is not enough information your question for a useful answer. The exception seems reasonably clear to me: Unity3d has specific rules about when you can call `Load()`, and you're not following them. Follow them, and all will be fine (i.e. defer your creation of the `AssetList()` object to an appropriate time, such as the `Awake()` or `Start()` method). If you need more specific advice than that, please fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do and explain specifically why you are unable to figure out how to get the code to work.

Comment: I do know that the Load() is built only to be called in Awake() and Start(). Is there is an alternative to make the constructor work?

Comment: What kind of "alternative" are you looking for? The obvious alternative is to comply with the Unity3d rules (for example, as I suggested in my previous comment). Did you try that? If so, what happened? If not, why not? Note that you can use the `Lazy<T>` class to defer initialization of objects; you'll still need to use it carefully, i.e. to not refer to the value until it's safe to do so, but it could help in this situation. Again: **there is not enough information in your question for any real, specific, useful answer to be provided**.